# How to use picasso to display image from URI? image does not show up

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am trying to get the app to display the signed in user's profile picture using picasso but the profile picture does not show up the uri thats generated by the `profile.getPhotoUrl()` method shows up but when i try to use that url to display the image it does not show up.
I did some research and found out that the reason why it is not showing up is because it is a contentProvider uri.
How can I get the profile picture to display?

[Here](http://content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F41/ORIGINAL/NONE/727944454) is what the uri of the profile would be like:

```
if (user != null) {
    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
        String providerId = profile.getProviderId();

        // this displays the email for some reason
        String uid = profile.getUid();

        //displays the name
        String name = profile.getDisplayName();
        //doesnt even display the email for some reason
        String email = profile.getEmail();
        //profile pic uri
        Uri photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();

        displayUser.setText(uid);
        displayName.setText(name);
        displayPhotoUrl.setText(photoUrl.toString());

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(photoUrl)
                .into(pic);
    };
}
```

Comment: this will keep replacing old image by new image. you are using same pic ImageView every time.

Comment: use `callback` to see the errors if the problem were with `Picasso`

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

OR

```
File f = new File(uri);
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(f).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the path from Uri and create a file Object with that.

```
File file=new File(uri.getPath());
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(file).into(imageView);
```